# unexpected ozonolysis products: short chain alkanes (methan, ethane, propane) as reaction products when ozone reacts with organic matter

Tags: reaction-mechanism, hydrocarbons, ozone

My question is which molecule or functional group reacts with ozone to yield short-chain alkanes?
Some background: I use ozone produced by an ozone generator with the aim to clean my vacuum instrument to reduce the blank for trace gas analysis (methane, ethane,...). The idea was that ozone would react with any labile molecules that are attached to the surfaces of my instrument. The hope was that the reaction products of these background organics with ozone can be pumped away with the vacuum and afterwards the surface would be clean and my blank is lower. Unfortunately, I observed an unexpected effect and found a large suite of short-chain alkanes (C1-C3) and also ethene and propene that desorb for hours from my surfaces (especially when liquid water is present). I was very surprised as reactions with ozone usually lead to O-containing functional groups while alkanes are not typical reaction products of "ozonolysis". Would it be possible that methyl- and ethyl-radicals are produced in an intermediate step which then abstracts an H atom from other molecules to finally yield alkanes?
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think it worked at all?

Comment: What is "*my vacuum instrument*" and how did you analyze and quantify gases?

Comment: @JochenSchmitt I would definitely [edit] in this information to the question.

Comment: @andselisk I tried to keep my question short so more details of "my vacuum instrument" can be found in this publication: http://www.atmos-meas-tech.net/7/2645/2014/. In short, it is a GC-IRMS method where we measure gases extracted from ice core samples, thus air from past times. The sample size is small with around 150 g of ice which has ca. 15 mL STP air and the concentration of the trace gases is very low in the range of 0.5 ppb for ethane. So I am dealing with tiny amounts of substance and thus contamination is a big issue.